# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Maintenance Plan doesn't proceed past first step

Tags: sql-server

We've been struggling the whole day to get a Maintenance Plan to work on our MS SQL Server.
Problem is: Whatever we do, when the Plan gets started (either manually, directly, or via the SQL Server Agent Job which got created automatically when we started the plan), only the initial step will be performed. After that 1st step the Maintenance Plan ends and reports success.
Originally we've planned to do the following steps in this order:

- Check Database Integrity (in case of error, repair DB)
- Backup Database
- Backup Transaction Log
- Shrink Database
  -- in case of errors, notify Operator

In this order, the Database Check will be performed and the Plan reports success.
We then changed the order - put the check at the end and start with the DB Backup.
In that order, the DB Backup will be performed and the Plan reports success.
This is where we took a screenshot of our attempts:
[Maintenance Plan Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myJEK.jpg)

Then we tried to change all "Success" constraints to "Completion" - again to no avail.
Running out of options, I took the liberty to ask the experts here, hoping that someone succeeded in this challenge already.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's great that you are putting thought into and making the effort to performing useful maintenance on your SQL Server!

While I'm not going to answer your question directly, other than to comment that shrinking of a database should not be part of regular database maintenance and is not considered to be a best practice. There are only a very specific set of circumstances where shrinking a database is advisable.

I will however make a suggestion: check out [Ola Hallengren's maintenance solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/) for performing the other tasks in your list. His is a tried and tested solution and will perform all of the maintenance tasks you describe above, and a couple of vey useful extras, with the notable exception of shrinking databases.

HTH Sean